# Adding a Parameter to an Event Listener created Dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a series of buttons dynamically. How can I add a parameter to the Event Listener `this.Purchase` below as follows: `this.Purchase(i)`? Simply adding "(i)" does not work.

```
      for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
         var button = document.createElement('input')
         button.setAttribute('type', 'submit')
         button.setAttribute('value', 'Purchase')
         button.addEventListener('click', this.Purchase)
      }
```

Comment: `() => this.Purchase(i)`

Comment: A better approach though would be to `button.setAttribute('data-index', i)` and use that from within the event handler instead.

Comment: Taplar, I am not sure I understand how to use the 'data-index' attribute within the event handler. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var thing = {
  Purchase: function() {
    console.log(this.getAttribute('data-index'));
  }
};

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var button = document.createElement('input');
  button.setAttribute('type', 'submit');
  button.setAttribute('value', 'Purchase');
  button.setAttribute('data-index', i);
  button.addEventListener('click', thing.Purchase);
  
  document.body.appendChild(button);
}
```

An example of using a data attribute with the event handler, as I mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Add a data attribute to each button, and call the purchase function in the onclick callback using the `this` keyword:

```js
var size = 3

for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  var button = document.createElement('input')
  button.setAttribute('type', 'submit')
  button.setAttribute('value', 'Purchase')
  button.dataset.idx = i
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    purchase(this.dataset.idx)
  })
  document.body.appendChild(button)
}

function purchase(idx) {
  console.log(idx)
}
```

Comment: If you set it as a dataset on the element processing the event, you don't have to pass it in.  Thats part of the whole reason of having it as a dataset element.

Comment: Thank you for your time symlink. However, Taplar's solution stated in the comments above works perfectly.

Comment: @Taplar if you want to call a separate function in your event handler, though, you have to pass `this` or an attribute of `this` to the function.

Comment: `addEventListener('click', this.Purchase)` as the OP had it is calling another method when the click happens.  Since the function is called via the event handler attached to the button clicked, the `this` inside the execution of the `Purchase` method will be the button clicked, not the element the function was originally attached to.

Comment: @symlink, I have tried your solution but it is not working. Upon clicking on any button in my "array" of buttons, I always get the last value as the value of the parameter passed (same actually for solutions provided by Taplar). The value of the variable is not "fixed" on the button during its creation, but passed at the time when it is actually clicked (which always corresponds to the value it had at the end of the for loop). Thank you.

Comment: @JF0001 make sure you are passing the `this` keyword. You'll have to post your code in a new question so people can take a look at it.